# I'm looking for a word that implies that someone can do a lot with a little

Tags: single-word-requests

To be more specific, I'm working on an MMO where players can pick different prophecies when creating their character.

This specific prophecy will limit players to only wearing common items with few stats on them (as opposed to epic or legendary items with 4 or 5 stats).

So the word needs to describe someone who makes the best of this situation.

So far, 'efficient' and 'resourceful' are the best ones I've been able to come up with but there's this little voice in the back of my head that's trying to remind me of a better one.

**EDIT:** Thanks so much for everyone's input. You gave me some great ideas and guided me in the direction I needed to go. In the end, the contenders were 'Scrounger', 'Resourceful' and lastly, 'Austere' which I decided to go with.

Comment: I like "resourceful" here.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Can you provide a sentence in which you may use the word? A sample sentence is required for posts like this.

Comment: I guess that the answer will likely fit most as an idiom rather than a single word.

Comment: Thanks @Hank. This won't really ever be used in a sentence, besides players just listing them: "My character has the 'hardcore', 'titangrip' and 'woeful' prophecies."

Comment: Please define MMO.

Comment: @David https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massively_multiplayer_online_game I'd guess

Comment: @k1eran — you shouldn't have to guess any more than I should.

Answer (score 0):

A ***scrapper*** makes the best of their circumstance by fighting on no matter the odds.  Conveniently, this word would also fit well in the context of your game as it implies competition.

> scrapper (noun):  A person who fights doggedly, who exhibits indomitable will.

e.g. He's a real scrapper, even against impossible odds, he always keeps fighting.

[Read more](http://www.yourdictionary.com/scrapper)

Answer (score 0):

It's close to a sense of *lean*:

> adjective, lean·er, lean·est.
>      (of persons or animals) without much flesh or fat
>      (of edible meat) containing little or no fat.
>      lacking in richness, fullness, quantity, etc.; poor
>
> spare; economical: a lean prose style.

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lean), slightly abbreviated.

or *spare*.

Added connotations of light in weight may or may not be what you're looking for.

On the other hand *mundane* (and its synonyms) contrast with *epic* or *magical* without implying a particular level of skill.

Answer (score -1):

The question borders on creative writing, but that being said, the idea of "drawing forth" might go hand and hand with the concept.

Taking one step even farther from that, this word is used more for drawing out thoughts and ideas (which is not what you're after) But this might work well if they are connected to Prophecies.. *which come close to ideas*

I might name them "**Elicters**" or "**Elicitors**" neither common words (or even real)

And look at it's root!

> [***elicit*** from Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/elicit)
>
> 1Evoke or draw out (a reaction, answer, or fact) from someone.
>
> ‘*I tried to elicit a smile from Joanna*’,
>
> 1.1archaic Draw forth (something that is latent or potential) into existence.
>
> ‘*a corrupt heart elicits in an hour all that is bad in us*’
>
> Origin
> Mid 17th century: from Latin elicit- **‘drawn out by trickery or magic’**, from the verb elicere, from e- (variant of ex-)
> ‘out’ + lacere ‘entice, deceive’.

A more common word might be "optimize", which is also closer to your question in the title. You could call them "**optimizers**'

> [**Optimize** from Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/optimize)
>
> Make the best or most effective use of (a situation or resource)

While optimize comes closer "doing a little with a lot", it does necessarily refer to the "little" part.

and I don't think it is nearly as evocative of use of prophecy

Comment: Thanks for the interesting take on this, Interestingly, 'optimizer' comes close to another word that is used often in ARPGs 'min-maxing', which is used to mean finely tuning your stats to get the most out of your build.